# Зачем поднимаются старые вопросы с принятыми ответами?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка

Я что-то не понимаю в работе сайта? Зачем сегодня (некоторые люди) пачками поднимают старые отвеченные вопросы, причем это не тот случай когда постится новый ответ - а тот, когда правится сам вопрос (незначительно) и в итоге вся лента засорена тем, что уже давно должно стоять подшитое на полках.
Нужно ли массово вносить правки (типа убрать в начале поста слова "добрый день", или поправить орфографическую ошибку) в старые вопросы?

Comment: Вносить правки нужно.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Всё хорошо в меру. Улучшать старые вопросы можно, если это сбалансировано с возможностью работы с новыми вопросами.

Необходимо смотреть на каждую серию правок по отдельности: если правки механические, например, просто убирают фразу «Добрый день», не исправляя других ошибок в вопросе, то следует попросить редактора перестать их делать, особенно, если они забивают поток вопросов, за которыми вы следите.

Если кто-то слишком увлекается, слепо применяя правило, не рассматривая последствия, то полезно на это указать на Мете (кто, какие конкретно правки, чем эффект в целом плох, как можно улучшить ситуацию).

Comment: Поддерживаю. Желательно улучшать вопрос насколько это возможно. Для новичков же простое удаление приветствий из их вопроса может быть и вовсе непонятным.

Answer (score 6):

Это происходит из за правок меток,
возможно из за закрытия вопросов (не уверен что это добавляет вопрос в текущие).

Правки меток позволяют лучше систематизировать вопросы. Также некоторые метки полностью удаляются, чтобы у новичков не возникало желания добавлять неправильные метки к новым вопросам.

Comment: Напишите зачем это делается

Comment: Про закрытие вопросов - непонятно, про правки меток - улучшать и полировать вопросы можно бесконечно, сегодня кто-то убрал - завтра кто-то вставил метки, в ленте в итоге не пойми что. Думаю для старых вопросов, годами лежаших не надо заниматся некромантией

Comment: @Mira, сейчас идет массовое сжигание метаметок.  Потерпите немного.

Comment: @Nofate теперь понятно :) спасибо что объяснили.