# Правка авторских отступов кода

Tags: обсуждение, стиль

Пример правки: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/131976

Некто взялся и исправил форматирование кода:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С одной стороны, как профессионал я могу только приветствовать такие правки, как многократно улучшающие читаемость. На работе мне приходится много читать кода и любые изменения кода, которые направлены на ускорение вникания в чужой код - они во благо. (Поэтому я так зверею, когда постят код в комментариях: более одной строки уже нужно прилагать больше усилий - просто хотя бы мысленно расставить переносы строк)

С другой стороны, как профессионал, я хорошо понимаю, что есть такая область, как стиль написания кода и лезть в чужой монастырь со своим уставом как-то непринято. Холивары годами идут о простых вопросах о отступах пробелами или табами! Тысячи копий сломано о вопросе открывать фигурную скобку на той же строки или открыть с новой! Вообще если задуматься, то новичку, который привык к какому-то стилю, наверное будет тяжело психологически вдруг увидеть, что его код заменили на какой-то чужой, который не факт, что работает, который нужно ещё проверить, что за ахалай махалай тут произошёл.

Вот как расценивать такие правки? 
Как улучшающие (акцептить) или ухудшающие (откатывать к исходной версии вопроса)?

Собственное мнение: правки улучшают вопрос, надо акцептить. Но есть сомнения, поэтому  решил уточнить на мете.

По теме нашёл только крайне далёкий вопрос ([тынц](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3386/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC-max-zs/3390#3390): правка 2 и фрагмент [16](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/87820) (форматирование блока кода)), автор ответа тоже полагает правку улучшающей.

Comment: Конечно, улучшающие (если автор явно не возражает)

Comment: @avp вот что-то я не вижу, чтобы в комментариях автора явно спросили. Утвердить правку и если не было возмущённых воплей, то значит "фух, прокатило без лишних уговоров"?

Comment: Ну, под возражением я имел в виду, что автор должен явно (в тексте вопроса-ответа или в комментарии) заявить, что не дело менять его стиль.

Comment: @avp а что Вы понимаете под стилем?

Comment: @avp я не совсем с вами согласен по поводу форматирования кода и разрешения автора, объясню почему: если автору удобно читать *простыню* кода то это его полное право, но если автор рассчитывает получить ответ то такие улучшающие правки я считаю **необходимыми**.

Comment: Не, *некто* взялся, а конкретно - я и взялся за правку этого примера кода )

Comment: @NickVolynkin так здесь же как раз стиль кода. То есть метка не к месту.

Answer (score 19):

Надо понимать что код сюда выкладывается не для автора, а для остальных. Поэтому исправление оформления на общепринятое является однозначным благом. Автору неприятно когда его код правят? А должно быть неприятно такое выкладывать!

Но есть несколько исключений.

Во-первых, стилистическая правка не должна менять смысл кода. Особенно осторожным надо быть при редактировании вопросов вида *"почему моя простыня кода без отступов не работает?!"*. Если риск что после простановки отступов простыня кода заработает - и никто не поймет в чем было дело.

*Особая осторожность - в коде на Python, Haskell и Yaml, где отступы являются частью синтаксиса!*

Во-вторых, стилистическая правка должна именно улучшать стиль - но не менять его под другой стайл-гайд. Не надо тут устраивать битв фанатов разных IDE.

В-третьих, никуда не девается принцип незначительных правок. Если во всем сообщении не хватает одного незначимого пробела - то вопрос о целесообразности его редактирования обсуждается в [других](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1951/178779) [местах](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2179/178779).

Comment: Насчёт IDE: IntelliJ вроде бы уже умеет распознавать исходный стиль кода и подгоняет к нему изменения. Т.е. если скобки были египетскими, то такими и останутся. Аналогично таб, два или четыре пробела.

Comment: Если после изменения отступов всё заработало, то скорее всего вопрос закрывается с формулировкой "Ошибка была вызвана опечаткой" (исключая упомянутые языки с семантически значимыми отступами).

Comment: @alexolut это если заметят, что оно заработало. А если никто не поймет, что код стал рабочим?

Comment: Если кому-то вопрос будет интересен, он проверит его работоспособность в текущем состоянии. И когда всё заработает, напишет коммент вида "У меня всё работает", как-то так. Но вообще, я не помню случаев, чтобы подобные правки приводили к фиксу бага. У Вас есть такие на примете?

Comment: @alexolut вы часто проверяете работоспособность кусков кода с непонятным назначением?..

Comment: @PavelMayorov если кусок кода нельзя проверить, я прошу ТС предоставить `[mcve]` или голосую за закрытие с аналогичной причиной.

Comment: @alexolut ну и какой смысл украшать кусок кода ежели вопрос - кандидат на закрытие? :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov так я и не говорил, что *такие* вопросы надо украшать. Мы обсуждаем последствия **уже** украшенного сообщения.

Comment: *"Особая осторожность - в коде на Python и Haskell"* Поэтому я не буду так форматировать код на этих языках )

Comment: Где можно почитать про принцип незначительных правок?

Comment: Ссылка на принцип незначительных правок нужна. ))

Comment: @NickVolynkin они слишком часто обсуждаются, а общего руководства нет. Добавил пока две ссылки с немного разными мнениями.

Answer (score 6):

Раз уж существуют разные системы записи кода, то предпочитаю править код в сторону ближайшей системы. В коде на картинке автор оставил одну фигурную скобки в конце строки. Её перенёс бы в начало следующей, а отступы не трогал бы.

И в ответе стараюсь писать код в стиле автора, когда ответ — это небольшие дополнения к его коду. Если же мой код не похож на код автора или если проблема именно в стиле записи, то оформлю ответ по-своему, чтобы поделиться и оформлением кода тоже.

Правку стиля одобрю, если покажется, что:

- у автора разнобой в стилях оформления;
- автор скопировал чужой код ради решения задачи, а стиль ему
  не важен;
- код переформатирован сниппетом, когда редактор менял что-то другое.

[В правке по ссылке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/131976) видно, что автор перемешал стили оформления.

Comment: @Bald Поправил текст, спасибо.

Answer (score 6):

Очень похоже (и часто так бывает), что вместо кнопки форматирования кода, которая добавит по 4 пробела в начало каждой строки, просто руками сдвигают строки с меньшим отступом. В таком случае сбивается отступ одного уровня, а остальное вполне нормально отформатировано. В таком случае правки надо принимать.

Это похоже тот вариант, который на скриншоте, хотя там и другие правки есть. Но всё равно я бы утвердил.

Comment: Кстати, да, очень популярная ошибка.

Answer (score 4):

Правки заключающиеся в расстановка отступов кода я считаю однозначным благом, так как читаемость кода только улучшается. В некоторых случаях(`sql`) я так же принудительно вставляю переносы строк, так как читать сложный `sql` запрос в одну строку мне кажется очень сложно.

Я с вами могу согласиться в плане того что не надо бездумно приводить код под себя: расстановка скобок, pascal/camel case - это то что может быть действительно непривычно автору, об этом лучше всего написать в комментарии с указанием ссылку на рекомендации, может быть автор просто не знает о принятых *соглашения* по написанию кода при использовании данного языка.