# Правка типичных ошибок

Tags: обсуждение, правки

Периодически я занимаюсь правкой сообщений в разной степени по орфографии, пунктуации, оформлению и согласованию текста, также иногда попадаются вопросы, где можно отметить код или добавить ссылки. Делаю согласно справке "Правка вопросов и ответов":

> Основные причины для редактирования:
>
> -исправить грамматические или орфографические ошибки;
>
> -прояснить суть сообщения, не изменяя его;
>
> -исправить мелкие погрешности или, если информация устарела, дополнить или обновить;
>
> -дополнить ссылками или указать полезные ресурсы по теме.

Также я прочитал на Мете в вопросах, ответах и комментариях, что думают в сообществе на тему схожих правок, и почерпнул полезную информацию, что стоит делать, а что — не стоит.
Несколько раз мне попадались типичные ошибки, и я рассудил так, что если нахожу типичную ошибку, то имеет смысл править её во всех вопросах и ответах, кроме закрытых и заминусованных.
После того как я начал так делать, убедился, что формально это допустимо и поощряется в сообществе, потому что за это есть награды, такие как, "Сыщик" и "Археолог".

Например, я правил написание слова атрибут. В русском языке оно употребляется с одной буквой т, в английском и латинском с двумя (собственно из-за английского варианта и пишут как "аттрибут"). На [https://dic.academic.ru/](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_fwords/6253/%D0%90%D0%A2%D0%A2%D0%A0%D0%98%D0%91%D0%A3%D0%A2) помимо написания "атрибут" есть вариант написания этого слова с "тт" в литературе 1865, 1907, 1910 годов. Насколько я понял, какое-то время оно употреблялось в таком виде. В самом сообществе есть метка атрибуты с одной буквой "т" [атрибуты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8B).
Первый вопрос, что думают другие участники сообщества по поводу написания слова "атрибут"? Какое написание более правильное?

Это объективная сторона вопроса, но есть и субъективная. Поэтому второй вопрос, так как я правлю сразу во всех вопросах/ответах, то грубо говоря, каждый день я могу выдавать множество правок. У самого меня пока не хватает репутации, чтобы править вопрос без проверки, и у меня нет доступа к очереди правок. Поэтому хотел узнать, если ли проблемы, которые я не вижу? Насколько критично большое количество правок и не стоит ли мне делать их меньше, править сообщение, только если там много ошибок из разных категорий или может вообще отказаться от такого подхода пока не накопится репутации? Может, я забиваю своими правками более важные темы или правки, отнимаю время у тех, кто проверяет правки.

Comment: Выражаю свою благодарность @Nowhere Man за конструктивную критику по этому вопросу.

Comment: [Дубликат](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1951/176217)?

Comment: Этот вопрос, ответы и комментарии я читал. Что-то я в нём подчерпнул, например, про правки закрытых и заминусованных ответов. Но вопросы остались и я их задал тут. Разница в том, что я не случайно нахожу ошибки, а ищу каждую ошибку по всем сообщениям и правлю их.

Comment: Я не вижу особых проблем с такими правками. Наоборот, положительный побочный эффект - проверяющие быстрее набирают проверки для знака ["Ревизор"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/83/steward)

Comment: Правки вроде бы поднимают посты на главную. И тратится время других участников на ревью, пока у вас не хватает репутации на правки не через очередь. Занятие благородное, но прям слишком много правок наверное не стоит делать.

Comment: А если достичь нужной репутации для правок без очереди, то какие проблемы останутся?

Comment: @Alexandr вопросы будут подниматься на главной, главная при массовых правках будет заполнена старыми вопросами (такое периодически случается, когда кто-то вручную массово правит метки, например). Я считаю, что это не большая проблема, если это не происходит постоянно. С другой стороны, при правках участниками с низкой репутацией такое не будет происходить, а на проверку небольших правок не требуется так уж много времени. Но с третьей стороны, массовые правки быстро исчерпывают лимит на 20 проверок в день у активных проверяющих, другие правки остаются без внимания.

Comment: Еще один потенциальный дубликат: [Зачем поднимаются старые вопросы с принятыми ответами?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2179/)

Comment: @Alexandr, вы теперь будете менять [одно слово "мучаться" на "мучиться"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/875046) и расставлять пробелы и большие буквы?  Вы как сами считаете, такие исправления радикально улучшают текст?

Comment: @Nowhere Man, я это делаю только со свежими вопросами и не так часто. На сколько я понял, в этом случае проблем нет.

Comment: @NowhereMan, да, я считаю, что это улучшает текст. Я был редактором. В этой среде и в том числе по стандартам, такие вещи являются ошибками на том же уровне, что написанное слово с ошибкой. Исправление ошибок улучшает текст. Сообщество по всему, что я прочитал так же на моей стороне. Были вопросы в деталях, я их учёл. Если у Вас есть предложения, я их готов выслушать. Если Вас что-то беспокоит или раздражает, так же можете написать, Вы мне кажетесь хорошим человеком и я готов выслушать и обсудить проблемы. Если тут не удобно, я оставил свою почту в профиле. Можете мне написать.

Answer (score 4):

Я считаю, не стоит специально искать старые сообщения с орфографическими ошибками, только чтобы исправить одну такую ошибку. Править старые вопросы стоит, только если в них есть несколько орфографических ошибок, существенно затрудняющих понимание текста, либо они имеют еще и другие проблемы (кривое форматирование, отсутствие необходимых меток). При этом, правка должна исправлять все проблемы, что может потребовать понимания тематики вопроса. Редактирование поднимает вопрос в списке активных; то, что массовое исправление некорректных меток поднимает кучу вопросов, уже достаточно плохо, не нужно к этому добавлять еще и орфографию.

Пример вопроса, где правка одной орфографической ошибки не привела к существенному улучшению вопроса: [Как в .Net по объекта->атрибутам, определить состояние "креста красного", "смерти GDI"?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1515621/) (только не закидывайте минусами, вопрос нормальный по сути, просто криво сформулирован).