# Почему поднятие старых вопросов на главной странице при их правках считается проблемой?

Tags: обсуждение, правки, поднятие-вопросов, главная-страница

Бытует мнение, что поднятие старых вопросов (при их редактировании) на главной странице - это плохо. Свежайший пример [тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12843/176217):

> Редактирование поднимает вопрос в списке активных; то, что массовое исправление некорректных меток поднимает кучу вопросов, уже достаточно плохо, не нужно к этому добавлять еще и орфографию.

Но есть же возможность менять сортировку, или вовсе смотреть вопросы в [соответствующем разделе по новизне](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Newest). Т.е. если не хочешь смотреть обновления старых вопросов - всегда есть способ (из коробки) этого избежать.

Почему же тогда поднятие вопросов на главной видится проблемой, с которой надо бороться? Запрещать массовые правки явных ошибок и т.п.?

Comment: Я, например, *хочу* смотреть обновления старых вопросов. Но осмысленные.

Comment: Я правлю свои старые ответы. Опечатки, иногда форматирование. Это проблема? Я люблю чтобы было красиво. А когда отвечаешь - спешишь, красиво может не получиться. Кроме того на сайте нет оформления формул. Я не сразу придумал как писать имеющимися средствами. Сейчас правлю оформление, иногда. Ещё правлю оформление чужих вопросов-задач, которые мне по душе. Если всё это запрещено, то не так прикольно.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat а кто решает, где граница "осмысленности"? Можно её как-то сформулировать объективно, или может быть даже автоматически как-то определять?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Ну, новые ответы точно интересны. Возможно комментарии, но я не помню, бампают ли они вопросы. Правки интересны, если они добавляют новую информацию (в вопрос или в ответы). *"автоматически как-то определять"* Да наверное можно, хоть по количеству символов в правке. Но компания обычно игнорирует feature-request-ы, как я понял. :/

Answer (score 5):

При редактировании вопрос отображается на главной странице и в списках "текущих" вопросов, чтобы дать участникам возможность прореагировать на новую информацию. Например, в вопросе не хватало нужных деталей, а после правки они появились, тогда на вопрос можно будет дать ответ. Исправление отдельных орфографических ошибок ничего не добавляет к вопросу и не дает достаточно оснований для привлечения к нему внимания. Не ставьте вопрос как "Почему поднятие на главную страницу является проблемой?", спросите "Стоит ли правка поднятия вопроса на главную страницу?", тогда многое сразу станет ясно.

> Запрещать массовые правки явных ошибок и т.п.?

Речь пока идет не о том, чтобы запрещать. Для начала можно просто сказать "Пожалуйста, не делайте это". Так как те, кто предлагает эти правки, не вредители, до жестких мер скорее всего и не дойдет.

Comment: Безусловно, "запрета" в том смысле, что это нарушает правила пользования сайтом (как, например, накрутка голосов) - нет. Но реакция противников этого почти всегда одинаковая - комментарий автору с просьбой так не делать, или очередной пост на Мете. Если участник новичок, а недовольство высказано высокореповым участником, это, скорее всего, будут расценено новичком именно как "запрет". Задавая текущий вопрос на Мете, я хотел понять причины недовольства и по возможности найти решение, которое бы всех устроило.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ "Но реакция противников этого почти всегда одинаковая - комментарий автору с просьбой так не делать, или очередной пост на Мете." - я что-то не припомню вообще каких-то  жалоб на массовые правки. Сам никогда не сталкивался, хотя периодически случается, что массово правлю метки, и главная заполняется отредактированными мной вопросами. Вопросы на мете по поводу поднятия старых вопросов есть, но вопрос - это просто вопрос, никто в итоге никому ничего не запрещал и особого недовольства я как-то не заметил.

Comment: @insolor вероятно, просто обновление меток прошло быстро и не успело привлечь внимание общественности. А недовольство, оно, вот, в ответах объясняется.

Comment: Кстати, исправление ошибок (опечаток или просто не очень грамотного письма) улучшает поиск по сайту. Например, пост может просто не попасть в результаты поиска, если ключевое слово будет в сообщении указано с ошибкой. Но для того участника, кто этот пост уже читал - улучшения как бы и нет.

Answer (score 3):

Поднятие единичных вопросов - это не плохо. Так даже Дух делает.

Плохо когда в результате массовых правок вся главная заполняется старьём, а новые вопросы теряются где-то на других страницах сайта.

Comment: Так  можно открыть раздел "Вопросы" и там всегда самые свежие вопросы в топе...

Comment: Удивительно что вообще кто-то смотрит главную, потому что это просто бесполезная страница и, как мне кажется, пора вообще от неё избавиться. Рудимент какой-то

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, я, наверное, в 95% случаев отвечаю на вопросы с главной, а не откуда-то ещё.

Comment: Обо всём этом написано в вопросе. Зачем запрещать людям вносить правки (пусть даже массовые), если можно просто открыть более подходящую для просмотра новых вопросов страницу? Хочется смотреть новые - надо смотреть новые, а не главную. Раз уж она реализована сейчас так как реализована.

Comment: @Qwertiy довольно странно выглядит тот факт, что отвечаешь с главной где ждёшь новые вопросы, хотя при этом все новые  вопросы спокойненько висят в разделе "Вопросы". ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, в раздел "Вопросы" я захожу если на главной всё интересное закончилось или если надо пару-тройку ответов, чтобы добрать 200 баллов за день.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я обычно слежу за изменениями в недавних вопросах.

Comment: @Danis для этого есть ссылка "Отслеживать" под вопросом. .... я смотрю люди вместо того, чтобы пользоваться нормальными доступными инструментами по привычке по старинке засухарились и пользуются одной страницей, которая рудиментарна

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, но на главной ещё вопросы со свежими ответами - может что-то интересное попасться. А в новых вопросах - это чисто зайти поотвечать - чего-то интересного, тем более, в ответах, там скорее всего не будет.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, если начать _отслеживать_ все потенциально любопытные вопросы, то весь инбокс по сути будет забит спамом.

Comment: @Qwertiy то есть отслеживать потенциально любопытные вопросы с бОльшим срезом, получается, хуже, чем видеть на главной **все** вопросы, даже абсолютно не интересующие?  Интересная логика))

Answer (score 0):

#### Я регулярно пользуюсь главной страницей, нахожу на ней новые интересные вопросы и отвечаю на них. НО не вижу никаких проблем с тем, что на главной странице иногда массово всплывают старые вопросы.

1. Старые вопросы тоже могут быть интересны
2. Главная страница довольно быстро обновляется
3. Использование главной страницы как основного инструмента не исключает использование, например, пользовательских фильтров в боковой панели (и других инструментов отбора интересных вопросов)

Answer (score -2):

### Я регулярно пользуюсь главной страницей, нахожу на ней новые интересные вопросы и отвечаю на них. Старых вопросов на главной странице быть не должно

Голосуйте за этот вариант, если считаете, что поднятие старых вопросов на главной странице при их правках является проблемой.

Answer (score -2):

### Главная страница рудиментарна, а интересные для себя вопросы удобнее находить с помощью других инструментов - вкладки "Новые", фильтров по меткам и др.

Голосуйте за этот вариант, если считаете, что поднятие старых вопросов на главной странице при их правках не является проблемой.